# Modifying void pointer in cpp

Tags: c++

Syntax for std::fread :

size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );

we can call std::fread with a character pointer and get the read data with the same character pointer.
eg:

```
char* data;
fread(data,5,10,file);
```

What i tried is to create a similar function which accepts a character pointer as a void* pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

void modify(void* ptr)
{
    char* temp = new char[50];
    strcpy(temp,"testing");
    __ptr=(void*)temp;
    std::cout<<"__ptr="<<(char*)__ptr<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    char* str;
    modify(str);
    cout<<"str="<<str;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the above code with http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php and I got the output as

**__ptr=testing**

**str=**

(a)**Why** str is not printing the string "testing"?

*I am assigning the address of a dynamically allocated variable to ptr.
So the value "testing" must be available in the heap even after the control returns from the method.*

(b)**How can i modify the function** so that i will get the output as

__ptr=testing

str=testing

But function prototype cannot be modified.

Please help.

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: title doesn't match body, random pointer mistreatment gives random results. Not a useful question.

Comment: This code doesn't compile without warnings/errors (http://ideone.com/yrOcHS).  Please fix that first, and then we can revisit.

Comment: this is basically `C`, if you want to do things the `C++` way, you should use iterators and streams.

Comment: @MSalters..actually i am writing a wrapper function for fread function. I just shortened the problem with the help of a simple example.

"random pointer mistreatment" can you please help me why you said like that? if you are right, then I think your answer may help me to solve the issue. :)

Comment: This won't even compile. there is no function that takes a reference to a `char*` to be called. If this compiles for you, kindly tell us what your toolchain is (and if it is TurboC++ I won't be a bit surprised at the crap it accepts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the function `modify()` takes a reference to a `void*` but you are actually passing a `char*`. This is not valid C++ and should not compile.

That said, there are some old C++ compilers out there (Visual C++ 6?) that have a kind of *extension*, that allows you to do that. That is when you are calling `modify(str)`, the compiler is creating a temporary value of type `void*` and initializing it to the value of `str`. Then the temporary is passed to the function and taking the address of the allocated memory. But, obviously, the `str` original value is never modified, so it remains uninitialized.

That's the main reason why the original C++ rule forbidding this is there: to protect you from this kind of bugs.

You have two solutions:

- Declare the function with the proper pointer type: `void modify(char*& ptr)`.
- Change the compiler!
- If you really wanted the function as is you could call it with `modify(reinterpret_cast<void*&>(str))` but I **do not** recommend that!

By the way, never name your identifier with two underscores (`__ptr`) these names are reserved for the compiler writers only·

Ah! I understand now the OP problem: his idea is to write a wrapper to `fread` that allocates memory, reads into it from a file and returns the pointer. It is easier if you just return the pointer the usual way. Using your `modify()` simplified example:

```
void* modify()
{
    char* temp = new char[50];
    strcpy(temp,"testing");
    return temp;    
}
```

And then, to call it:

```
char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(modify());
```

Comment: So you think the compiler is creating a temp to pass as a non-const reference? Egads.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, I think that VC++6 (and maybe later versions, I didn't use them much) used to allow that kind of code.

Comment: I know VC++ since at least 2008 supported non-const-references to *return values* of temps, but this (what you described) is Ugly with a capital U.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Look at the [list of VC++ extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx). The other extensions are more or less sensible, but that one is madness!

Comment: @rodrigo..I think you can solve my problem. So that i am asking the same question again in a different manner as the title says.

Then how std::fread works.?
Syntax :
size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
We are passing a character pointer to the same function right?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph: I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but generally speaking, if you return a value from a function using a non-const reference argument, you have to pass the exact same type (without the reference). So either pass in a `void*` or else return a `void*` from the function. Or write a template. But I fail to see what it has to do with `std::fread` because that functions does not modify the pointer passed to it: it is a C function, and in C functions cannot modify the arguments.

Comment: @rodrigo.Thanks.
But a final question..

char* readData = NULL;
fread(readData, 1, 100, fileStream)

My doubt is how fread is able to modify the pointer readData so that the read data from file is available with the same?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph: `fread()` does not modify the pointer, it modifies the memory pointed by the pointer. These are two totally different things. Think of `ptr = X` vs. `*ptr = X`.

Comment: @rodrigo..i can't modify the function. Because the wrapper function is already defined by the tool. I can't modify it. The only thing i can do is to write code inside it.
So in short, i cant modify the "modify" function so as to return a void pointer. By keeping this syntax, i have to make the read data available in the main function. That was the problem i was facing.

As you said in the last comment, i tried to modify the value of that pointer directly.
But i failed as it is a void pointer. I think void pointer cant hold any data.

But your valuable comments helped me to solve my issue :)

Comment: Note: This answer answers the original question; however the question was substantially modified in Edit #5, so this answer no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

From the valuable answer and comments from @rodrigo, i was able to solve my problem.
I modified the function.

```
void modify(void* ptr)
{
    char* temp;
    temp = (char *)ptr;
    strcpy(temp,"testing");
}
```

This solved all the issues!

Comment: If applied to the code which is currently in the question, this writes to a wild pointer, since `str` was never initialized to point anywhere.